# Confusion about axially symmetric gravitational fields in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I'm currently reading the following documents on axially symmetric gravitational fields in general relativity.

[Weyl - On the theory of gravitation](https://link-springer-com.access.library.unisa.edu.au/article/10.1007/s10714-011-1310-7)

[Synge - Relativity: The general theory](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/synge-relativity-general.pdf)

Both documents perform the following magic that escapes me completely.

Given a line element of the form

$ds^2 = f dt^2 − d\sigma^2,$

where

$d\sigma^2 = [h_{11}(dx^{1})^2 + 2h_{12}dx^1 dx^2 + h_{22}(dx^2)^2] + l(dx^3)^2$,

and the coefficients $h_{ij},f,l$ are functions of the spatial coordinates $x^1$ and $x^2$ only. Both authors then proceed to state that the expression in the square brackets can be expressed in "isothermic" form given by

$$ h[(dx^1)^2+(dx^2)^2].$$

Can someone explain what strange sorcery is being performed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fact is all about two dimensional Riemannian geometry (in fact, classical geometry). The tensor in the square brackets is a Reimannian metric on the two dimensional plane. It is a famous fact from the theory of two dimensional Riemannian metrics on the plane that there exists a change of coordinates that transforms any general Riemannian metric into a conformal one $h(x,y) \big(dx^2 + dy^2\big)$. These coordinates are sometimes called isothermial coordinates, sometimes called conformal coordinates. Since having actually isothermic coordinates (coordinates on two dimensional surfaces immersed in 3D that are curvature line parametrization and conformal/isothermal at the same time) is something more restrictive, that term "isothermic" is technically not quite correct. The first thing that pops up on wiki on this topic is [a wiki article on isothermal coordinates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_coordinates) A standard way of proving the existence of these coordinates is via [the Beltrami equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_equation) (see the section on metrics on planar domains).